# Help digesting schematic layout

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics

Can someone help me figure out what the little letters and numbers mean on the pins of this ic?

They're used throughout various ics in this iPhone 6 schematic. Are they indicating sequence?

For example A1 happens first then A2 etc or? [image]

Sorry that it's showing up blurry. It's crystal clear on my phone. Not sure why it's compressed like that

Comment: [This question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247466/iphone-schematic-help?rq=1) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked two questions:

> Can someone help me figure out what the little letters and numbers mean on the pins of this ic?

As *Mike F.* has mentioned, my answer to [this previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247466/iphone-schematic-help) also answers this part of your question - those are the [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) ball numbers on the IC.

> They're used throughout various ics in this iPhone 6 schematic. Are they indicating sequence?
>
> For example A1 happens first then A2 etc or?

They are indicating the order (layout) *of the balls on the IC*, but not what happens *functionally*. For example, across the top of IC `U1401` in your image, the pins `A2` `B2` `D2` `C2` are shown as connected together, so they are all *used* at the same time.

Note that there are a variety of different BGA layouts, so you should check the manufacturer's datasheet to confirm the specific ball numbering for an IC. Based on available photos, the device shown as `U1401` *might* be manufactured by Texas Instruments, however its datasheet does not seem to be publically available.

Just as an example, here is a diagram from Texas Instruments showing the magnified layout for one of their other BGA packages (larger than `U1401` in your schematic):

[image: Texas Instruments example BGA layout]
<sub>Image source - [link](http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/166/8156.F5338.JPG)</sub>

Notice that the circles for each "ball" are *not* complete; that is a convention indicating that this is the top (not the bottom) view of the package (confirmed by the text also saying "top view"). You can see that the upper row of the grid layout is row `A` and the left column is column `1`. Then the row letters and the column numbers increment, producing the "sequence" like `A1` `A2` etc. that you noticed on that schematic.